# Как с помощью list comprehension создать двумерный список, где каждый элемент-это отдельное четное число из данного списка?

Tags: python, list

Вводятся строки, состоящие из целых чисел, разделенных пробелом, до тех пор, пока пользователь не выведет пустую строку. Все введенные строки необходимо сохранить в список. На основе этого списка, используя list comprehension, сформировать двумерный список, где каждый элемент будет представлять отдельное четное число. Результат вывести на экран.
Я написал небольшой код, но он не работает должным образом.

```py
rows = []
while True:
 row = input()
 if not row:
  break
rows.append(row)
nums = [[int(n) for n in row.split()] for row in rows]
print(*nums)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Дело в том, что  программа в итоге не выводит двумерный список и все может она сделать-это  вывести пустые квадратные скобки, после того, как я вывел пустую строку.

Answer (score 2):

В общем, все правильно, кроме прерывания цикла получения данных от пользователя (пустая строка c в переводом строки не равна None) и проверки на четность.

Cделать можно так:

```
rows = []
while True:
    row = input()
    if row=="":
        break
    rows.append(row)

l = [[int(x) for x in a.split() if int(x)%2==0] for a in rows]
print(l)
```

Здесь вы проходите по одномерному списку `a.split()`, проверяя, что число четное (`not int(x)&1`), и выводите как отдельный список. Вместо конструкции `not int(x)&1` можете использовать классическую `int(x)%2==0`.

Comment: Так по заданию мне нужно сформировать двумерный массив, а не одномерный.

Comment: ну так я так и сделал. уберите * в print(*l)

Comment: Хорошо, а начало моего кода, где создается список и чисел, правильное?

Comment: я исправил ответ.